# What data type is good for a IO buffer in C#

Tags: c#, python, sockets, io

I am using asynchronous socket API in C#. In the client side, I need a buffer to store the binary data read from the server. And other client logic will check the buffer, unpack the head to see the length, if the length is less than that indicated by the header, continue. And next time we check the buffer again. For the network logic, I need to maintain this buffer, and I want to know what data type should I use.

In python we use a string as a buffer, but I don't think this is gonna work in C#. Inefficient, Encoding problem (I need to parse the binary data my own, not necessarily to a string), Frequently changed. What about stringbuilder? Any other suggestions?

Comment: use `byte[]` which happens to be the natural data type for socket I/O.

Comment: @EugenRieck Why give an answer as a comment?

Comment: @EugenRieck That requires a management of buffer, like a startIndex and Length. And the length of array is fixed, what about communication  traffic pulse?

Comment: There is a class called BinaryReader and BinaryWriter especially to handle primitive data types

Comment: @AndrewShepherd because it is hort and non-original

Comment: @zoujyjs I typically use a set of fixed-length arrays, that rotate through buffer, interpretation, freelist. This reduces management to the length (which is returned by the socket I/O), as start index is zero. It saves a lot on allocation/deallocation, which more than overcompensates the appearant waste.

Comment: @EugenRieck I would argue two things: firstly, it is not hort, and secondly, hort is not actually a word.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I fully agree. Hort is an actual word only in german, but this is an english list, and "Hort" has no relation whatever to IT, much less to programming. Hopefully this was not too hort. Oups!

Answer (score 2):

I would use `byte[]`. It will get the job done.